# How to pass a row as a parameter to a Postgres function?

Tags: postgresql

I have a function build_details(), which takes as one of its parameters, a single row/record from another table.

This is what I want to do, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT build_details(
    SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1,
    1000,
    TRUE)
```

I want to take a single row from my_table and pass it to the function so that I can make it run. How do I call the function from the terminal with a record from my_table?

Answer (score 12):

It's much simpler that that. While one would expect it to be ...

```
SELECT build_details(my_table.*, 1000, TRUE) FROM my_table LIMIT 1;
```

... the actual syntax is:

```
SELECT build_details(my_table, 1000, TRUE) FROM my_table LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I just merged our answers together seeing this popup to the top I answered it and didn't realize your answer was already using the row object, and I didn't want to gank it. You beat me to the punch.

Comment: Why on earth did you do that?

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL I have no idea what you tried to accomplish by replacing my answer with yours, but I've just put things back as they were before your fiddling.

Comment: cool, I'll just submit my own then. =) It's basically the same method, except explained.

Answer (score 11):

I would do it like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
CROSS JOIN LATERAL build_details( my_table, 1000, true )
LIMIT 1;
```

You can see this working with some sample data below.

```
-- create some sample data,
CREATE TABLE foo(bar)
  AS VALUES (42::int), (7);

-- select a row object, representing every row in foo;
SELECT foo 
FROM foo;
```

Create a function that takes a [row type of `foo`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) a `bool` and an `int` and simply raises a notice and returns true.

```
CREATE FUNCTION build_details( myrow foo, j int, k bool )
RETURNS bool AS $$
  BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', myrow, j, k;
    RETURN true;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now we can use the above syntax passing the row object representing a row in `foo`, with two other variables an `int` and a `bool`.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN LATERAL build_details(foo::foo, 1000, true);
NOTICE:  (42), 1000, t
NOTICE:  (7), 1000, t
 bar | build_details 
-----+---------------
  42 | t
   7 | t
(2 rows)
```

You can of course, still use `LIMIT` or whatever predicates you'd like.

Comment: Note that `SELECT * FROM foo, build_details(foo, 1000, true)` is a shortcut the final query. It does an implicit lateral join.

Comment: I stumbled across this answer by accident when trying to work out why I couldn't just call `select some_func(foo.*)...` to send my row to the function. The secret was  `select some_func(foo::foo)...`. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil The row is already typed to the table, the only time you should need that is if you want to cast a row type to a different row type.

Comment: That's what I hoped. Unfortunately, I needed to explicitly cast it. Strange but true in my particular case.

Answer (score 5):

## Using a subselect to reselect the row

This seemed to work:

```
SELECT * FROM public.build_details(
    (SELECT r.*::public.my_table FROM (TABLE public.my_table) r LIMIT 1),
    1000,
    TRUE);
```